# how to delete all column data excluding sid(foreign key) and license column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
+----+------------+---------+--------+
|sid | date       | user_id |license |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |   he   |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |   do   |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |   as   |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |   to   |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |   we   |
|  6 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |   be   |
|  7 | 2016-06-23 |    NULL |   go   |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: could you please provide an *actual description* of your problem by editing your question, as well as *what you have tried* and *why it failed*?

Comment: actually am trying to delete all data that related to a student_id from many tables but i want the license key not to be deleted.

Comment: **edit!** your original question. and be more precise. provide useful information. for example: there is not a single reference to "student_id" in your question - *what is it?*. and before doing anything else: **[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UPDATE `calls` SET `date` = NULL, `user_id` = NULL
```